# Enchantment Auras and returning to hand

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If my opponent uses a spell with the effect "return all nonland permanents to their owner's hand", does that include enchantments - auras?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield. An Aura attached to a permanent is therefore also a permanent, and will be returned to its owner's hand by that effect.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, assuming the enchantment is not also a land, it counts as a nonland permanent. It would be returned to your hand by [Coastal Breach](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCoastal%20Breach%5d), for example.

We know that enchantments go to the battlefield when they resolve.

> [303.2.](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Enchantment) When an enchantment spell resolves, its controller puts it onto the battlefield under his or her control.

And finally, we know that any card on the battlefield is a permanent.

> [110.1.](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Permanent) A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield. [...]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to return your enchantments to your hand.

They are technically nonland permenants. Section 110.1 of the rules states this.

Comment: I appreciate the help.

Comment: If you are going to mention that one section of the rules states this, it would be a good idea to include that section of the rules.

Comment: Part of the reason for quoting that section of the rules is that the rule numbering changes sometimes, and without the quote, if a removal and an addition meant rule 110.1 became rule 109.2 we'd have no idea what's being talked about here.